# Set a logic in the middle between p-chips and formcontrolname

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng, form-control

Need help with `p-chips` and reactive forms:
I have a structure in formgroup which is built like the database item.

```
valueSeperatedBySemi = "hi; hello; Whoop"
```

And I need to set it like this:

```
<p-chips formcontrolname="myFormCName" separator=";">
```

But it's not working since the `p-chips` needs an array. I cannot change  `valueSeperatedBySemi` to an array.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`separator` property is used to replace default enter key to add an item to the chips component. So it won't be useful in your case.

I think you should set an intermediate variable between the component and your data. Let's call it `values`: a string array.

```
<p-chips [(ngModel)]="values"></p-chips>
```

First, you need to transform your input data into a string array to fill your chips component:

```
this.valueSeperatedBySemi = "hi; hello; Whoop";
this.values = this.valueSeperatedBySemi.split("; ");
```

Then, if you want to get back your data formatted like in your database, you have to transform it back this way:

```
this.valueSeperatedBySemi = this.values.join("; ");
```

Of course, you can easily adapt this with formControl.

See [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-chips-demo-8tcsnx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: thanks for the fast answer, but the solution doesnt work. i tried this earlier and i get an error int he console:

ngModel cannot be used to register form controls with a parent formGroup directive. Try using formGroup's partner directive "formControlName" instead.

any other idea?

Comment: ok - i found the solution on my own  - [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"